# certbot d'ont works correctly

Tags: linux, debian

certbot certonly --webroot -w /var/www/html/ -d mrcoudreau.fr -d [www.mrcoudreau.fr](http://www.mrcoudreau.fr)

An unexpected error occurred:
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /directory (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate is not yet valid (_ssl.c:1123)')))

Why I have this error please ?

I don't know What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

```
certbot --apache
```

Saving debug log to `/var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log`

The requested apache plugin does not appear to be installed.